# Button unresponsive when pushed out of column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a template which has two Bootstrap columns in it.

The first column has a form in it which is populated by the backend. The result of this is that the form is wider than the column and the button is being pushed out into the area of the second column.

The part of the button in the first column is clickable but the part in the second column is unresponsive.

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

#firstColumn{
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

#secondColumn{
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
  
form{
  background: tomato;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10;
}
    
button{
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" id="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="firstColumn">
    First Column
    <form>
      <button>Click me!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="secondColumn">
    Second Column
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/mpoo/pen/dyMmmwp

How would you go about making the entire button clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `z-index: -1` to the second column

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

#firstColumn{
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

#secondColumn{
  border: 1px dashed green;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
form{
  background: tomato;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10;
}
    
button{
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" id="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="firstColumn">
    First Column
    <form>
      <button>Click me!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="secondColumn">
    Second Column
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @olegoriginal that does the trick. I'd been playing with natural numbers of z-index but did not think of using a negative z-index.